# how does websocketpp handle connections when set_tls_init_handler is not set?

Tags: websocket, websocket++

I see that I have to define an `on_tls_init` and have the `set_tls_init_handler` to point to this `on_tls_init` for secure connections. What happens when `set_tls_init_handler` is not set? Does webscoketpp go head with the connection over `ws://` instead of `wss://` or is the connection dropped?

Answer (score 1):

WebSocket++'s transport security behavior is based on which config your endpoint uses. If your endpoint is configured to be secure, i.e. using a config, like `websocketpp::config::asio` whose transport socket type performs TLS encryption then not defining a tls init handler (or not returning a valid TLS context from it) will result in connections failing with an `invalid_tls_context` error.

If you want plain/unencrypted/"ws://" connections you should use an endpoing config that does not perform TLS encryption (for example `websocketpp::config::asio_no_tls`). An endpoint compiled with that config will ignore the tls handler.